# 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'

Tags: python, exception

Whenever I try to read Excel using

```
part=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name = mto_sheet)
```

I get this exception:

> <class 'Exception'> 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'

This is if I use Visual Studio Code and Python 3.11. However, I don't have this problem when using Anaconda. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by the latest version of `openpyxl`.
You can fix it by downgrading to a lower version

```bash
pip install --force-reinstall -v "openpyxl==3.1.0"
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! hope they fix that error in ver 3.1.1

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, too.

Comment: Congratulations on outperforming ChatGPT

Comment: Upstream issue: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1963

Comment: Alternatively, updating to `3.1.2` would be enough.

Comment: @Leaderboard 3.1.2 is not yet available on conda. Would force-installing it with pip create issues in a conda environment?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous it should be fine to install using pip inside a conda environment.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like the issue is fixed in openpyxl 3.1.2

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```

Comment: Yep, once I upgraded openpyxl, this error message went away.

Comment: I'm on 3.1.2 and am still experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround: create new excel file, with default worksheet name ("Sheet1" etc.) and copy and paste data here.

(tested on Python 3.10.9 + openpyxl==3.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers changing openpyxl version to 3.1.0 works, but if you for some reason do not want to change it you could also try read excel like this:

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = excel.parse(sheet_name)
```

for some reason I had to use other openpyxl version and it worked for me